Why thread safety is listed as a benefit of immutability?
I was reading about Records in C# and read that they are immutable. And thread safety is written as a benefit of immutability. How immutability provides thread safety? I tried a code sample claiming to provide predictable results by using Records because they are immutable rather than using shared mutable object. I tried the code and the results were unpredictable:
public record SharedData(int Value);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        ImmutableRecords();
        //MutableSharedVariable();
}

static void ImmutableRecords()
{
    SharedData sharedData = new SharedData(0);

    Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sharedData = sharedData with { Value = sharedData.Value + 1 };
        }
    });

    Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sharedData = sharedData with { Value = sharedData.Value - 1 };
        }
    });

    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

    Console.WriteLine(sharedData.Value);
}

When I tried to comprehend this code, I see that although sharedData is immutable but it can be replaced with a new instance and that is same as mutable object behavior in the context of multiple threads accessing and writing it. And so the results are unpredictable.
Then why thread safety is listed as an advantage of immutability?
The other questions doesn't clarify this.
Although the immutable class object is unchangeable but the reference variable that holds it is mutable and still it is inconsistent in using in multiple threads.
Even if we make reference variable also immutable (if at all that can be done), then also what is the end result. If we want only reading and no writing, then that can be done with an ordinary mutable variable by doing just reads and no writes.
Then how does immutability help in thread safety at all?

You are sharing the variable sharedData across threads, which is mutable.

Thread-safety is a characteristic of an object not a variable (or field etc). Realising that distinction will realise the error in your thinking.

I see that although sharedData is immutable but it can be replaced with a new instance and that is same as mutable object behavior in the context of multiple threads accessing and writing it A variable containing a mutable object can be reassigned, and the object can be altered. A variable containing an immutable object can be reassigned, and the object cannot be altered. All your code does is prove that a variable can be reassigned - which isn't particularly interesting since that is always true for all variables - regardless of whether they are pointing to an immutable object or not.

we need concurrent writes for thread safety and not the reads, the reads are already thread safe (immutable or mutable). then what is benefit of immutability in thread safety if we can't change them

@teenup Did you read what I wrote? Don't just skim it. Read it. Think about every word I have written. Then come back here. An immutable object cannot be altered. That can be beneficial in a great many situations. For example you could pass around a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-8.0 and be 100% sure that the list being passed around will not be altered. This means I can, for example, enumerate that list without worrying that another thread might be altering it (unlike say a List<T>).

Your basic statement seems to be that immutable doesn't solve problem A. But it isn't designed to solve that problem. It is designed to solve problem B. If you need to solve problem A, then you need a different solution - one designed to solve problem A. That doesn't mean immutable is useless - sure it is useless in solving problem A but very useful in solving problem B.

Did you forget to mark an answer?

Thread-safety is a characteristic of an object not a variable / field.
The fact that an object is thread-safe does not magically make code that has two different threads writing to a given variable act the way you expect.
The issue here is that immutability helps for certain problems. But it isn't designed to solve the issue you show in your code. So to you it seems useless. And to solve that issue - yes, indeed it is useless.
Your expectation here seems to be "I want to be able to atomically increment this value". I suspect ImmutableInterlocked.Update is likely what you want (thanks @TheodorZoulias).

Then how does immutability help in thread safety at all?

Here is an example for you.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bob = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                bob.Add(4);
            });

            Process(bob);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> toProcess)
        {
            foreach(var item in toProcess)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

This code is using a mutable non-thread safe List type. Run it. You will get an exception. Now let's try with an immutable type:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bob2 = ImmutableList.Create<int>(1, 2, 3);

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                bob2 = bob2.Add(4);
            });

            Process(bob2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> toProcess)
        {
            foreach(var item in toProcess)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that this does not throw an exception. Why not? Because ImmutableList is immutable. Even when you Add to it - it doesn't impact the list. Instead it creates a new one. This allows you to pass the list around and not worry about how it is used elsewhere. This is an example of why immutability is helpful.

I would say that thread-safety is an attribute of a group of related variables/fields/memory locations/registers/etc. "Object" is the name of one formalism for grouping. The issue at the heart of it is, a single thread can only change the members of the group one-by-one, and for whatever reason, we do not wish any other thread to be able to see the group in a half-way changed state.

The excellent answer by @mjwills answers directly your question. Here I will just show how to fix your code. ​​The ImmutableInterlocked is a static class that helps at updating atomically mutable references of immutable types. You could use the Update method of this class like this:
ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref sharedData, x => x with { Value = x.Value + 1 });

The signature of the Update method:
// Mutates a value in-place with optimistic locking transaction semantics via
// a specified transformation function. The transformation is retried
// as many times as necessary to win the optimistic locking race.
public static bool Update<T> (ref T location, Func<T,T> transformer) where T : class;

You can study the source code here.
You can use it to update atomically fields of record class types, but not fields of record struct types. For these you need to lock.

Nice, I learnt something new. https://dotnetfiddle.net/AyWKUG
